# Can Bot see the whole group?

Tags: bots, chat, google-hangouts

So, I want to create a bot/incoming webhook that would read all the messages in a group and copy it to a spreadsheet.
The thing I'm asking here is, can bots or incoming webhooks read the whole group message?
In the google chat api page, in the REST api reference bit, link( https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/get ) there is something called >spaces.messages.get
but does this get all the message in a group, if so how?

Comment: Hi, was my answer useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find messages in google spaces using chat.api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72026386/how-to-find-messages-in-google-spaces-using-chat-api)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently list all the messages from a space, with something like `spaces.messages.list`. You can only retrieve these messages individually with [spaces.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/get).

There is a feature request in Issue Tracker related to this:

- [Feature to get list of messages in DM / Room in Hangout chat.](https://issuetracker.google.com/127691116)

I'd suggest you to [subscribe to this issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.