# How to find messages in google spaces using chat.api

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-chat

I want to be able to pull all text messages from a google chat space.

I'm looking at the [spaces.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/get)but it assumes you have the ID of a message. In similar programs (MS Teams), you can call an endpoint to list all message ID and then call the message API to extract the contents of an ID. However, google chat has no such API.

Has anyone come across a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is currently not possible

There is already a respective [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/127691116) on Google Issue's Tracker.

I recomment you to star it to increase visibility and hope that it will be implemented soon.